# Difference between declaring typedef

Tags: c, typedef

I have recently started out in C and want to know the difference between

```
typedef struct 
{
      char *name;
      int age;
} Person;
```

and

```
struct Person
{
       char *name;
       int age;
}
typedef struct Person Person;
```

thank you

Comment: I hope  your problem is solved. If it is solved by any of the answers here then please accept it. If you find answers to the duplicate of this question as more convincing, then I suggest you to close this question by accepting the most relevant (close to the solution you wanted) answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference as such. `typedef` just creates alias of a present datatype.

However, in first case you can declare the `struct` variables as `Person me;`, i.e. using `Person` only. In second case you can either use `Person me;` or `struct Person me;` both are valid.

I find latter one more readable and understandable.

**Extra Notes:**
BTW your second declaration has a minor syntactic error:

```
struct Person
{
       char *name;
       int age;
}; // You missed this ';'
typedef struct Person Person;
```

You can also combine these two statements as:

```
typedef struct Person
{
       char *name;
       int age;
}
Person;
```

Comment: if I would to declare an object instance in the first example, how would it look like compared to the 2nd example?

Comment: As I said in my answer itself: To declare object of `struct` in first case you will do it like this: 
`Person some_person;  // that's it`

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, the `struct` is also given the name (called "the struct tag") `Person`, but in the first version that is omitted, making `Person` the only name for the structure.

I prefer the former whenever possible, there's no need to introduce extra names.